# What is the inverse rake operation to rake gems:unpack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I would like to unfreeze the gems which where previously `rake gems:unpack`ed. What is the operation for this? So far I know only the method of `rm -r vendor/gems`. For `rake rails:freeze:edge` there is `rake rails:unfreeze`. Is there such inverse rake task for gems too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inverse for gems:unpack, but as you pointed out you can delete them yourself.  There's nothing wrong with this, since unpack just copied the files without any further integration.

To confirm this, you can run:

```
rake -T
```

And get a list of all rake tasks.

Comment: thanks, you confirmed there is nothing bad than with the rm vendor/gems